# Preserving the state of a screen

Tags: swift

I have two `viewcontrollers`. `vc1` is a form that holds the user's input values.`vc2` is a canvas. I have a button in `vc1` that shows `vc2`. How do I preserve the values in `vc1` so when the user closes `vc2`, `vc1` has the values previously inputted?

I know `NSUserDefaults`, but it would require more work. I'm just wondering if I show `vc2` as modal via segue, is it possible to preserve the values of `vc1`?

Here's how I show `vc2`:
[image]

Here's how I dismiss `vc2`:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it so that when you present vc2 from vc1, the presenting instance of vc1 is still alive and has all the properties intact.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> How do I preserve the values in vc1 so when the user closes vc2, vc1 has the values previously inputted

If you're doing this correctly, those values never went away. There is nothing to do. When VC2 is dismissed, VC1 was always in existence and was never changed. If that's not what you are seeing, then you are not properly dismissing VC2. (Perhaps you are making the elementary beginner mistake of presenting a whole *new* copy of VC1 instead.)

Comment: I updated my question with some more details.

Comment: My answer is correct. Your second segue is a segue. That's wrong. It is not a dismissal. You are going `VC1` -> `VC2` -> `a different VC1`, not `back to VC1`. A dismissal (going back) would be to call `dismissViewControllerAnimated` or use an _unwind segue_.

Comment: Can you provide detailed actions?

Comment: Can you do a search? This has been explained many times here.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is now working and I will be able to fix my other screens. Thanks!